# How to promptly get workitem history with tfs java sdk?( with out workitem.open())

Tags: java, tfs

for reasons, i must use tfs java sdk, so i always need workitem.open() to load revisions for each workitem from workitemclient.Query(),like below code:

```
WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = workItemClient.query(wiql);
for(int i = 0; i < workItemCollection.size(); i++)
{
    WorkItem workItem = workItems.get(i);
    workItem.open();
    workItem.getRevisions()
        .forEach(r -> {
            //..."System.History").getValue());
            //..."System.History").getOriginalValue());
        });
}
```

if don't use open(), Revisions must be empty;
that open() method cost 55 millseconds for each workitem,that's unacceptable。

so any suggestion for better efficiency ？ Thanks a lot。

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////make it/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

i make it that cut the time.
use SQL like blow :

```
String sql = "select [System.Id],[System.ChangedBy],[System.ChangedDate],[words]"
    + " from Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.WorkItemsEverable"
    + " left join Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.WorkItemLongTexts on [System.Id] = [ID] and [System.Rev] = [Rev]"
    + " where FldID=54" // behalf History field
    + " and"+conditionSql;
```

conditionSql : " id in ('12','1324','1')"

now use this method, average cost mills for retrieve history(changedby,changedDate,History) just 2~4 mills（test case is 30 ~ 1000 workitems）

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////still/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

any advise for better code/efficiency would be appreciate。

Answer (score 0):

The revision history can only be retrieved for work item fields available in the collection [WorkItem.Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.fieldcollection.aspx?tduid=(0b021289a8d919d2c98e68fbfb7e370d)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-OsjQy_R8m41b204PmY.taw)()), so if you used the below code to get the workitem revision history you will NOT see the history but end up reloading the current workitem object again and again.

```
   foreach (Revision revision in wi.Revisions)
            {
                Debug.Write(revision.WorkItem);
            }
```

You may try to get value of fields in the work item revision:

```
// Returns a work item object
            var wi = GetWorkItemDetails(id);

            // Get All work item revisions
            foreach (Revision revision in wi.Revisions)
            {
                // Get value of fields in the work item revision
                foreach (Field field in wi.Fields)
                {
                    Debug.Write(revision.Fields[field.Name].Value);
                }
            }
```

Helpful blog: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx

Comment: Thanks  but you first part C# code can't help my java question. i test in C# case, revision always be auto load, so there won't appear same open() delay before getRevisions in C#.   i  make it today by Querying in TFS's Database.   done.